# Eclipse (or JDK?) shifts keyboards

Tags: keyboard, java, android, eclipse

My installation of Eclipse, while using Java in Android projects, is changing my keyboard's layout when I write any invalid statement. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView iv
    }
}
```

When I try to complete this snippet:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_imagem);
```

after typing "iv", the character set in my keyboard is screwed, and instead of a QWERTY keyboard (I have Portuguese language defined, and don't have other keyboards in control panel), I end up with an AZERTY keyboard, and the auto-complete shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> is disabled.

In Windows, other applications are is still normally in QWERTY. I thought this could be Windows shifting the keyboard's language, but I disabled those shortcuts. In other applications, everything is normal. I don't know if this is related with JDK or Eclipse, because it also happens in Java projects.

Additional Info: I use Windows 7 and Java JDK, in 64 bits. For Android, I use the ADT Bundle, not the Eclipse plugin. Reinstalled ADT and JDK, with fresh versions, today, with no effects.

Many thanks for any info

Comment: Note, Windows shifts the keyboard input language on a per-application basis, so this still sounds like it might be something going wrong with that even though you say you have the shortcut disabled.

Comment: thanks. i'll try the "Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator" (read about it here: http://superuser.com/questions/66561/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows) to remove this per-application curse.

Regards, Luis

Comment: now it gets even weirder. i notice the shortcut in eclipse to autocomplete (Ctrl + space) also changes to the chinese keyboard. but i dont remember of ever having this installed! And the fact is, in keyboards and languages, the only one i have is portuguese (see here: http://furioushamster.com/docs/language_portuguese.png), both the default layout and the one created with MKLC. 

I dont have English or Chinese installed language or keyboards, and i'd remove if i knew how. Or at least disable them