# Windows 10 suddenly shows a lot of keyboard languages

Tags: windows-10, input-languages, windows-10-pro

I know this was asked many times before, but I couldn't find a recent answer, and it seems that Windows 10 has changed a lot and some answers went out of date in a year only!

Where did these languages come from? They are not even present in the language settings.
I didn't even install them and I don't even know what they are.

Is there a recent way to prevent this (and fix it if it happened)?

[image]

**My windows specs:**

[image]

Comment: See if this link can help with you:https://superuser.com/questions/1252704/windows-10-keeps-randomly-adding-keyboard-layouts

Comment: @Candy Thanks, but as I mentioned, a lot of answers went out of date. Some of them even suggest going somewhere that doesn't exist anymore or not even useful.