# Can't remove English (United Kingdom) from keyboard languages

Tags: language, input-languages

In addition to failed attempts to stop [UK language from automatically being added](https://superuser.com/questions/1146973/keyboard-layout-united-kingdom-is-automatically-added), now (with latest windows update), i can't even remove it fro keyboard languages.

[image]

I hve nowhere chosen UK, neither in Windows installation or anywhere. Why Windows  everytime  add that UK to our languages, as we haven't chosen that. Even more, now I can't remove it ? o_O

Comment: You can't remove _current display language_. Change Windows display language first (see option above `+ Add a language`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove ***current*** display language. First, change `Windows display language` (see that option and gray-bluish drop-down list below).

The `Windows display language` drop-down list offers merely from *installed* languages.

[image: languages]

Comment: Isn't there an option to use a keyboard layout that's different than the display language?