# How to get rid of US language in Windows 11

Tags: keyboard, language, windows-11

I am sure I had same issue with Windows 10 and solved it. Now I can't solve it with Windows 11.

I have English (United Kingdom) language which is also locale language. I don't have English (United States) anywhere - see pictures.

However my keyboard with English UK is US. In Windows 10 it was not a problem - I had only one *keyboard* (US) with English UK *language*.

In Windows 11 I have now two keyboards if I use switch shortcut but in the settings there is only one keyboard and I can't delete the second one as it's not there.

To recap: I want to have ENG English (**United Kingdom**) **US** keyboard and remove ENG English (United States) US keyboard. All "duplicate" questions are ***not*** applicable here because I do ***not*** have ENG English (United States) language anywhere in the system.

So again - **I need UK English language with US keyboard layout** and nothing else.

Removing Preview key from registry doesn't work - it is back as soon as I sign in.

Keyboard layouts when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

[image: Keyboard layouts when I press Ctrl+Shift]

Language settings - only UK

[image: Language settings - only UK]

UK Language options

[image: UK Language options]

Comment: [The commands to remove an unwanted language pack is identical to that of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1146973/united-kingdom-keyboard-language-is-added-automatically?rq=1). Have you tried that solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Windows 10 from automatically adding keyboard layouts (i.e. US keyboard)](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Comment: look at the pictures - I do NOT have ENG US **language**. So I cant remove it because its not in the settings. But when I press keyboard switching sequence I have 2 keyboards. One for UK Eng **language** with US **layout** and one US Eng **language** with US **layout**.. I only need one.. Hope that clears it. Thank you

Comment: @BoppityBop - Have you tried the command from the duplicate? By running the command you are able to then remove it. Suspect your hatred for me is preventing you from accepting a possible solution. I have read your question, and determine the behavior is identical, to that of existing questions with answers.  You have a language listed that isn’t installed, which language that is might be different, but the command to remove it will be identical.

Comment: nope. I actually completely forgot about that spat on Meta and I didnt read the comments authors. Nothing to do with that. It is sounds very similar to what could happen on W10 - I had that problem when I installed W10 few years back and I solved it.. However this same thing in W11 doesnt want to be fixed. I tried all 3 different solutions from offered duplicates to this question - and I could not fix it.. Honest.

Comment: The second answer of [How to prevent Windows 10 from automatically adding keyboard layouts (i.e. US keyboard)](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke) helped me in this case: Add the keyboard that you want to remove, and then remove it...

Comment: After I remove the layout, is there also a way to prevent it from re-appearing? It feels like it gets added on every windows update.

Comment: I fixed this 10-15y ago on my LAN (4 PCs, 2 being Windows XP Pro in virtual machines on the 2 others), thanks to the luminous advice of another user. When I reported this on an MS forum similar to the present SuperUser one, I got severely lynched. MS is clearly determined to prevent any way to get out of this decade-long exasperating deliberate flaw. Versailles, Fri 23 Jun 2023 16:21:30 +0200, edited 16h23:50

Comment: I noticed that under Time & language > Language & region > Related settings section, "Administrative language settings" option, "Administrative" tab, "Language for non-Unicode programs" I still had US English (unwanted). Changing this to UK English (using the "Change system locale..." button) seems to have got rid of the US keyboard option.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have any additional keyboard layout:

[image]

That belongs to language that you don't have installed:

[image]

Then simply:

1. Install that language (*English (United Kingdom)* in the above example)
2. Go to language details and install the keyboard layout (*Polish (Programmers)* in here)
3. Uninstall the whole language language pack

After that pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should reveal only languages and keyboard layouts that you have actually installed in your system.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me too. So just to clarify for other readers, if you manually *add* the language + keyboard combination that you want to *remove*, then after you remove that language, then it will no longer show up.

Comment: I can confirm with the latest update to Windows 11 as of the date of posting this works. Switch to the language you want to REMOVE, let it log out, come back in, switch to the language you want, let it log out and log back in. Then remove the language you want to REMOVE and the taskbar thing disappears.

Comment: It comes back after restart, unfortunately. Not sure, what I did wrong

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue with other languages: I have a German Keyboard and a German system but I'm forced to have a US English language layout.

Since I very often press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> accidentally, I end up changing the layout by accident.

Sadly, I can't remove English as language since my only existing language is German.

However, I found that installing the US language and *then* removing it, solved it for me.

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-remove-language-switcher-from-the-taskbar-on-windows-11/) did the trick for me.

`Settings` or `Win+i` > `Time & language` > `Typing` > `Advanced Keyboard settings`

Check **Use the desktop language bar when it’s available**.

Then click `Language bar options below`, under `language bar` check **Hidden**.

Comment: That's a useful contribution but it doesn't really solve the problem.  For example I might want UK English and French keyboards so I might need to have the the language bar visible, I just don't want US English available.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 11 settings (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>), select *Time & language* > *Language & region*:

1. Open the *Language options* of any listed language, press <kbd>Add a keyboard</kbd>, select *US Qwerty* to add it, then click on the triple dots next to *US Qwerty* and select *Remove* to remove it.
2. Related settings section, "Administrative language settings" option, "Administrative" tab, "Language for non-Unicode programs" > press the "Change system locale..." button, replace "US English" with the layout of your main language.
3. Reboot.

Comment: it comes back after the next windows restart

Comment: @Zippp it comes back after some time on my computer too. I found an additional workaround, added it in my answer as point 2, try that.

Comment: point 2 is a must for me. fixed it after restart.. i was going to write an answer but you were already here :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Windows 11. My installed layouts were:

1. English / US layout
2. German / DE layout
3. **German / US layout  <-- I don't want this!**

I want only #1 + #2, but not #3 (German with US layout).

To remove #3, go to Settings (`Win`+`i`) > Time & Language > Language & Region. In the "Language" section at the top, there were two entries:

1. English (United States)
2. **German (Germany) <-- configure this one**

[image]

Click on the "..." icon next to the "German (Germany)" entry, select "Language Options". On the new page, scroll down to the "Keyboards" section. There were two entries:

- German QWERTZ
- **German QWERTY (US) <-- remove this**

Click on the "..." icon next to the "German QWERTY" entry and select "Remove".

[image]
*(Note: I took this screenshot after the German QWERTY entry was already removed, so it actually shows the desired end state.)*

Done!