# How to prevent Microsoft Pinyin keyboard from randomly switching between Chinese and English modes?

Tags: windows, input-languages

I'm currently using the Microsoft Pinyin keyboard for Chinese character input on Windows 10 19042.804. This keyboard has both Chinese and English modes. However, when switching between different programs, the mode randomly changes between Chinese and English.

- I have disabled the <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> shortcut, which switches between the two modes, so I cannot be accidentally switching
- Most solutions I've seen (e.g. [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/976947/keyboard-language-keeps-changing-in-windows-10)) talk about random switching between different *keyboards*, rather than different *modes* in the same keyboard as in my case.
- [Another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/66561/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows/66564) said that "Windows maintains different input language for each thread". However, despite not changing the keyboard mode between different programs, the mode still randomly switches.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103566/165358) helps.

Comment: @harrymc All the mode switch shortcuts are all off and unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: Is your problem also that of hitting the Shift key by mistake?

Comment: @harrymc just retested - pressing Shift does not change input mode

Comment: If this is caused in your case by some other key or combination, then it can be blocked. Otherwise, if this is caused by some program in English mode taking briefly the focus, then it cannot be blocked except by you finding out which is that program.

Answer (score 2):

Copying from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-make-the-microsoft-pinyin-really-default-to/7d8cdf9a-3472-423e-9e9a-96a98d0c34ce)

It seems like it is context dependant. When you select a english textbox, the keyboard attempts to be sMArt and change to english for you. Certain applications like notepad, Word, Powerpoint can be configured to stay on chinese. Others, like chrome, not so much. Very disappointing behavior.